# Resolve multiple promises and send angular 2 http request

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-http

I need to fetch two things from my storage, which gives me two `Promises`. Next up, I need to use these two promises to compose an angular 2 HTTP request. But I cant figure out a way to correctly compose these steps. I always end up with an `Observable<Observable<Response>>`.

```
    let tokenPromise = this.getToken()
    let registrationTokenPromise = this.getRegistrationToken()

    Observable.zip(
        tokenPromise,
        registrationTokenPromise,
        (token, registrationToken) => {
            let headers = this.headers(token)
            return this.http.post(`${this.apiBase}/users/registration-token`,
                { registration_token: registrationToken },
                headers
            )
        })
```

How can I correctly solve this to receive an `Observable<Response>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an `Observable<Observable<Response>>` because `Observable.zip` returns an `Observable` and the `http.post` returns an `Observable`.  In order to unwrap one of the observables, you will need to `subscribe` to the `Observable.zip`

```
Observable.zip(
        tokenPromise,
        registrationTokenPromise,
        (token, registrationToken) => {
            let headers = this.headers(token)
            return this.http.post(`${this.apiBase}/users/registration-token`,
                { registration_token: registrationToken },
                headers
            )
        })
        .subscribe(response => {
           //do something with response
        })
```

Comment: Yes I've chained two `subscribe` calls together and now my request fires. Thank you.